CloudFormation template for Nginx image deployment to ECS not working
I've been trying to deploy a React frontend application using a CloudFormation template, and the deployment itself appears to work, the nginx image built and ran in docker locally also works fine.  However the stack never finishes deploying, it gets stuck in a loop preparing and draining the services:
CloudFormation template:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
    FrontendImageName:
        Type: String
        Default: frontend_client
        Description: The name of the frontend image in AWS ECR
    ClusterName:
        Type: String
        Default: frontend-ecs-cluster
        Description: The name of the ECS cluster
    ServiceName:
        Type: String
        Default: frontend-ecs-service
        Description: The name of the ECS service
    DesiredCount:
        Type: Number
        Default: 1
        Description: The number of tasks to run

Resources:
    VPC:
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
        Properties:
            CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
            EnableDnsSupport: true
            EnableDnsHostnames: true
            Tags:
                - Key: Name
                  Value: VPC
    PublicSubnet1:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
            MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
            AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs ""]
    PublicSubnet2:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
            MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
            AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""]
    InternetGateway:
        Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    AttachGateway:
        Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
    PublicRouteTable:
        Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
    PublicRoute:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Route
        DependsOn: AttachGateway
        Properties:
            RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
            DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
            GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
    PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
        Properties:
            SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
            RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
        Properties:
            SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
            RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    ALB:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties:
            Subnets:
                - !Ref PublicSubnet1
                - !Ref PublicSubnet2
            SecurityGroups:
                - !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
            Scheme: internet-facing
            Type: application
    TargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            Protocol: HTTP
            Port: 80
            TargetType: ip
            HealthCheckPath: /health
            HealthCheckPort: 80
    ALBListenerRule:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
        Properties:
            Actions:
                - Type: forward
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
            Conditions:
                - Field: path-pattern
                  Values:
                      - /*
            ListenerArn: !Ref ALBListener
            Priority: 1
    ALBListener:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
        Properties:
            DefaultActions:
                - Type: forward
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
    ALBSecurityGroup:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupDescription: Security group for ALB
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            SecurityGroupIngress:
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 80
                  ToPort: 80
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    FrontendLogGroup:
        Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
        Properties:
            LogGroupName: !Sub "/ecs/${ServiceName}"
    ECSCluster:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
        Properties:
            ClusterName: !Ref ClusterName
    FrontendTaskDefinition:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
            Family: !Ref ServiceName
            Cpu: "256"
            Memory: "512"
            NetworkMode: awsvpc
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                - FARGATE
            ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt FrontendTaskExecutionRole.Arn
            ContainerDefinitions:
                - Name: frontend
                  Image: !Join
                      - ""
                      - - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                        - ".dkr.ecr."
                        - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                        - ".amazonaws.com/"
                        - !Ref FrontendImageName
                        - ":latest"
                  Essential: true
                  PortMappings:
                      - ContainerPort: 80
                  LogConfiguration:
                      LogDriver: awslogs
                      Options:
                          awslogs-group: !Ref FrontendLogGroup
                          awslogs-region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
                          awslogs-stream-prefix: frontend
    ECSServiceSecurityGroup:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupDescription: Security group for ECS Service
            VpcId: !Ref VPC
            SecurityGroupIngress:
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 80
                  ToPort: 80
                  SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
    FrontendService:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        DependsOn:
            - ALB
            - ECSServiceSecurityGroup
        Properties:
            Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
            ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
            TaskDefinition: !Ref FrontendTaskDefinition
            DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCount
            LaunchType: FARGATE
            LoadBalancers:
                - ContainerName: frontend
                  ContainerPort: 80
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
            NetworkConfiguration:
                AwsvpcConfiguration:
                    AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
                    SecurityGroups:
                        - !Ref ECSServiceSecurityGroup
                    Subnets:
                        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
                        - !Ref PublicSubnet2
    FrontendTaskExecutionRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                      Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: FrontendTaskExecutionRolePolicy
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: "2012-10-17"
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                                - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
                                - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                                - ecr:BatchGetImage
                            Resource: "*"
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - logs:CreateLogStream
                                - logs:PutLogEvents
                            Resource: !GetAtt FrontendLogGroup.Arn

And the nginx configuration:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /health {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }

    location / {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /latest {
        return 403;
    }

    location /api/latest {
        return 403;
    }
}

And the dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Build React App
FROM node:alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve React App with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Any advice appreciated.
I've tried altering port numbers on the nginx configuration and the template incase of conflict.  But I can't work out what is going wrong.
Since locally it builds and works I'd expect it to work correctly when built from the ECR.
I have also tried to get the log stream working to no avail, but that is not the primary issues.

Two issues I see right away:

You don't appear to be assigning a security group to the ECS Service. That means all ports will be blocked on the service and the ALB/TargetGroup will never be able to connect to the service. You need to add a security group to the ECS service that allows inbound connections on port 8080 from the load balancer.

The Target group has the correct port 8080 configured for the health check, but it has port 80 configured for all other traffic. Both port configurations on the target group should be port 8080. That is the port you are telling the Target Group to connect to your ECS service on, so they have to match the port your ECS service is listening on.




I've tried altering port numbers on the nginx configuration and the template incase of conflict.

This is a single container running on Fargate, so there is no possibility of a port conflict here.

Thanks for the prompt response:
I've added an AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup for port 8080, associated it with the AWS::ECS::Service
And corrected the ports to 8080, but the result is the same, tasks start then drain.

You need to determine the reason they are being drained. In the target group web console, does it say the targets are unhealthy? In the ECS service UI, if you filter by "all tasks" instead of "running tasks" it should show the stopped tasks and list the reason they were stopped. Also, it looks like you need to add CloudWatch Logs permissions to the ECS Task Execution IAM Role so that the task can write log output. After making that change, check the task's logs for any errors.

You've fixed the logs, thank you, it does appear to be related to the health checks:
Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:964218689560:targetgroup/tacos-Targe-BGIJHQAZSZGS/f4c0b63991d186f3)
It looks as though the deployments are clean though, but once deployed the logs go dead, until the health check causes them to be drained.  I can't reach the endpoint through either the load balancer DNS or the public IP associated to the task itself.

Maybe you should update your question to show the latest CloudFormation code. It sounds like there is still a port configuration issue somewhere, or a security group rule issue.

Done, i've moved back to using port 80 across the board since you indicated that was not the issue.

The task's security group only allows traffic from the load balancer, so your test to hit the ECS task's IP address directly would not have worked. You would need to open the security group to all traffic (or to your public IP) before doing that test.

And you are sure you rebuilt the image after changing the settings to port 80 everywhere, and pushed that image, and that's the image you are deploying in ECS now?

You might also try removing access_log off; from the nginx health check setting temporarily, because seeing those in the log right now would be helpful for debugging.

One day I hope I am half as good with AWS as you sir.  Thanks so much.
